# How to solve "Error converting string to float " where strings are obtained through regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, string, floating-point

I have extracted numbers from text using regular expressions.

```
df1['numbers3'] = df1['TEXT'].str.findall(r'(\d+\.\d+)').apply(','.join)
```

I now want to convert them into float to make some comparisons.

I have tried this

```
df1['numbers3'].apply(lambda x:float(x))
```

and

```
df1['numbers3']=df1['numbers3'].astype('float')
```

Here is an example of my data sets

```
d = {'numbers3': ['1.9,1.4,2.0,1.5,1.1,1.3,3.7,3.8']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I tried to simply remove the quotes using

```
df1['numbers3'] = df1['numbers3'].str.replace('"', '')
```

But still getting same error. Please Help!

Comment: your regex is not working correctly. Also, what is the goal? You will have one row (the data in TEXT) with a list of numbers all in one column. Pandas REALLY doesn't like having lists in a "cell".

Comment: Why save as a string then when extracting? Use `df1['numbers3'] = df1['TEXT'].str.findall(r'\d+\.\d+').apply(lambda x: float(x))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sounds like a good idea, but I am getting this error- float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Comment: Try `df1['numbers3'] = df1['TEXT'].str.findall(r'\d+\.\d+').values.tolist()`

Comment: So, I tried doing it in 2 steps: df1['numbers3'] = df1['TEXT'].str.findall(r'\d+\.\d+').values.tolist() then df1['numbers'] = df1['numbers3'].apply(lambda x: float(x)) and getting error as "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'"

Comment: `df1['numbers3'] = [[float(l) or l for l in x] for x in df1['TEXT'].str.findall(r'\d+\.\d+')]`? It is not quite clear what you expect.

Comment: So, do you realize you are working with nested lists? What is your intention? Why cast each number to float if it is already an object?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My intention is to be able to do some calculations and comparison with the numbers extracted, which was not possible in string format

Comment: Show the code then

Answer (score 0):

Your string is a *list* of numbers; you need to break them up before converting each to a float.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn this string into a list of floats, you first turn the string into a list, and then each element into a float:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'numbers3': ['1.9,1.4,2.0,1.5,1.1,1.3,3.7,3.8']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df1.numbers3.apply(lambda x: x.split(',') ).apply(lambda x: [float(i) for i in x])
```

I'm not totally sure this is what you actually want, though.

Comment: this works for this dataset, but when I apply to my full dataframe it again says: ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: So there's something different between your sample data and the actual data. Try to post data that really represents your dataset, else we can't help you much

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the list of a single string of a lot of numbers into a list of strings of numbers, then turn each of those into a float as well. Pandas isn't necessary here, and you could add this list to a df as well.

```
d = {'TEXT': ['1.9,1.4,2.0,1.5,1.1,1.3,3.7,3.8']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df1 = d['TEXT'][0].split(',')
floats = [x for x in map(lambda x: float(x), df1)]
```